# How do remove a class after revealing it?

Tags: javascript

I have a gif that I am trying to remove after 3 seconds of it being  toggled on. Here is the breakdown:

- When the user clicks on the orange square it gets removed.
- A gif is toggled on.
- After 3 seconds
  I want the gif to get removed and the brown circle toggle on.
  I know I have to use the setTimeout  method, but I do not know how to apply it. Can anyone help?

```js
//Removes square
function remove(){
    this.remove();
    
}

//Adds gif
let gif = document.querySelector(".gif");

function showHide(){
    gif.classList.toggle("hide"); 
}

//Removes gif
```

```css
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body{
    background-color:pink;
}
.parent{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


.gif{
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 1; 
}
.hide{
 display:none;
}
#square{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:orange; 
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 2; 
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.circle{
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:brown;
    border-radius: 50%;   
}

.hide_2{
    display:none;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> gif reveal </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent"> 
      <img class="gif hide" src="kuromi.gif">
        <div id="square" onclick="this.remove();showHide();">
            <div class="circle hide_2"></div>
        </div>    
       
    
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question would be better if you explained what's blocking you from using the setTimeout method and why you say you don't know how to apply it.  As it is asked right now, you are basically just asking someone to write a working solution for you.  I think it would be a better question, and generally more useful to more people in the community, if you had an actual question (sentence with question mark).  The title has a question mark, but the body of your question doesn't seem to coincide with the title. Is the issue "how to remove a class" or "how to set a timer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is occurring because you are trying to show the circle which is a child of square after deleting the square. So making the square a sister element of the circle would get your job done.

```js
//Adds gif
let gif = document.querySelector(".gif");
let circle = document.querySelector(".circle")
let square = document.querySelector("#square");

function showHide(elem) {
  if (elem == 'square') {
    square.classList.toggle("hide");
  } else {
    circle.classList.toggle("hide");
  }
  gif.classList.toggle("hide");
  setTimeout(() => {
    gif.classList.toggle("hide");
    if (elem == 'square') {
      circle.classList.toggle("hide");
    } else {
      square.classList.toggle("hide");
    }
  }, 3000)

}

//Removes gif
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}

.parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gif {
  border-radius: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

#container {
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}

#square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: brown;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hide_2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> gif reveal </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <img class="gif hide" src="kuromi.gif">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="square" onclick="showHide('square');"></div>
      <div class="circle hide" onclick="showHide('circle');"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I may ask one more question, once the circle is added how do I reverse it back to the gif for 3 seconds and then back to the square if the user clicks on the circle?

Comment: @Jen You can implement something like in the edited using a simple if statement and a parameter

Comment: Once again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```js
function showHide(){
    gif.classList.toggle("hide");    
}

function handleOnClick = () => {
    remove();
    showHide();
    setTimeout(() => showHide(), 3000); // This will get executed after 3 seconds (in milliseconds)
}
```

I, however, would prefer not to use `toggle` method as sometimes it might work a little bit quirky.

```
const showHide = (hide) => {
  if (hide) gif.classList.add("hide");
  else gif.classList.remove("hide");
};

function handleOnClick = () => {
    remove();
    showHide(true);
    setTimeout(() => showHide(false), 3000);
}
```

It should work the same way, but this way it is clearer on what action you want to do.